# jsonObjectWithData causing memory crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am getting response data from a server using AFHTTPRequestOperation in AfNetworking 2.0

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[ServiceHelper instance] getRequestData:postDict :[ServicesConfiguration GET_DOCUMENTS_URL]];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSDictionary *returnData = [[ServiceHelper instance] getReturnDictionary:responseObject];

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

The getReturnDictionary method called on the responseObject is a simple JSON Serializer..

```
- (NSDictionary *) getReturnDictionary : (NSData *) data {

    if ( data == nil ) {
        return [NSDictionary dictionary];
    }

    NSError * error = nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@",error);
        return [NSDictionary dictionary];
    }
    else
        return jsonDict;
}
```

This works fine for smaller amounts of data. But when the response object is like 100mb, the app hangs on

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

And then about 15 seconds later, the app crashes due to a memory error.
I think its pretty self explanatory that its the massive size of the data, but shouldn't it be able to handle it?

If I get the data directly from an [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:]; - it works without hanging or crashing. As this is what I was doing originally - but switching to AFNetworking to display a progress bar more easily.

Any thoughts or tips are appreciated.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: there is no error. Says "The app <App Name> on <My Device> terminated unexpectedly. Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory error"

Comment: It kind of known issue which is reported before. I updated the answe. Will also file a ticket for AFNetworking.

Comment: Note that 100MB of JSON will parse into maybe 500MB of iOS objects, maybe twice that.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
So You have 2 options to solve this:

> Blockquote

Use NSJSONReadingMutableContainers as options

> Blockquote

If previous does not work you are facing a known issue like below:

[iOS Download & Parsing Large JSON responses is causing CFData (store) leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634736/ios-download-parsing-large-json-responses-is-causing-cfdata-store-leaks)

So now you have 2 options:

1. Use native JSON Serialization
2. First downloading the JSON files to disk without using AFNetworking and than parse.